# Existence of projectives in the category of torsion abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Consider the category of torsion abelian groups. This category doesn't have enough projectives by the following argument.

Suppose $C_2$ (cyclic group of order 2) is the homomorphic image of a projective $P$, where $x\in P$ maps to the generator of $C_2$. There is a surjective map $C_{2^k}\to C_2$ by sending one generator to the other. Since $P$ is projective, it lifts to a map $P\to C_{2^k}$ sending $x$ to some generator. Hence $x$ has order at least $2^k$. Since $k$ is arbitrary, $x$ has unbounded order, a contradiction since $P$ is torsion.

**Question**: does this category have *any* (non-trivial) projectives? If so, what is an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a nonzero projective in the category. Consider its injective envelope $D$ in the category of abelian groups, which is a torsion divisible module. Thus $D$ is a direct sum of Prüfer groups and so there is a nonzero morphism $f\colon P\to G$ where $G$ is a Prüfer group, say $G=\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, for some $p$.

Let $G_0=\{0\}\subset G_1\subset G_2\subset\dotsb$ be the chain of subgroups of $G$; then, since $f\ne0$, there is $x\in P$ such that $f(x)\in G_1$, $f(x)\ne0$.

Now, for each $n>0$, the multiplication by $p^{n-1}$ defines a surjective morphism $\mu_n\colon\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\to\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ and the morphism $f$ lifts to a morphism $g_n\colon P\to\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ such that $\mu_n\circ g_n=f$.

In particular $g_n(x)\in G_n$ (otherwise $\mu_n(g_n(x))=0$), so the order of $x$ must be greater than $p^n$.

This is a contradiction, so $P$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I think I follow except for one part: how do we know that $f(x)\in G_1$? And is this even necessary for the proof?

Comment: @Ekie $G_1$ is essential in $G$, so it intersects the image of $f$ non trivially, hence it is contained in the image. It's not strictly necessary for the proof, but it makes it more direct.

Comment: @Ekie It's the same idea as the one in your question, as you see, but Prüfer groups are used. I think László Fuchs showed me this proof, which I recollected here from memory, some 30 years ago.

Comment: @egreg: I wish I had your memory.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The argument in the question woke up something in my memory. Then I wrote the proof and became sure I had seen it before; finally I remembered having talked about it with Fuchs and that he had shown the argument (or a very similar one) to me and my PhD advisor.