# List of standard notation of concrete categories

Tags: category-theory, notation

Is there somewhere a relatively big list of concrete catiegories with their standard notations? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Examples) is a list of some of them, but for example the category of affine spaces is missing from here. Is there at all a standard notation for it?

Comment: I have a large collection, if you are interested. However, the notations, e.g., abbreviations are not unique in the literature. For example, the category of [torsion abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038786/existence-of-projectives-in-the-category-of-torsion-abelian-groups) has several different names. Or have a look at the names [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/CTSheet4-2013.pdf): $AbGp_{t.f.}$ etc.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Categories_in_category_theory) is a list of $51$ categories.

Comment: Yes, I am interested. For the specific case of category of affine spaces, I didn't find any notation (abbreviation) in your sources cited so far.

Comment: The category of affine spaces is denoted "Aff" [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+space).

Comment: @Dietrich: that's confusing; I'd also use Aff to denote the category of affine schemes, for example. There isn't common notation for the category of affine spaces because it just doesn't come up very much.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, exactly. This is what I meant, there is no standard notation, and these abbreviations are not always unique (see my first comment).